# How to allow user to edit only object created by self?

Tags: python, django

I have a custom user model implemented in my pigeon management app and I want to allow user to edit only pigeon added by self. In backend every user can see only pigeon that are his own based on filter. My problem is that a user can edit all pigeon in the database if they pass to the url an aleatory number that corespond to a pigeon pk in the database.

```
# Pigeon Model
    class Porumbei(models.Model):
        id_porumbel = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        data_adaugare = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True)
        crescator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
        serie_inel = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False, unique=True,
                              help_text="Seria de pe inel. Ex: RO 123456")
        ...

# My url
    path('porumbei/editare/<int:pk>/', porumbei.views.editareporumbei, name='editareporumbei')



# I try somethin like this
    class Crescatori(admin.ModelAdmin):
        def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
            if obj is not None and obj.crescator != request.user:
                return False
            return True

        def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
            if obj is not None and obj.crescator != request.user:
                return False
            return True
```

I use login required to protect the views but I don't know how to deny a user to edit a pigeon that he don't own. 'To be more coincise, lets suppose that user A has added a pigeon with pk 5 and user B added a pigeon with pk 6. With my implemented url, user A can edit pigeon at url domain/porumbei/editare/5. If user B pass the same url, he can edit too that pigeon but it doesn't belongs to user B. How can I avoid this? Thank in advance.

Comment: These views aren't in the admin so including the model admin is a bit misleading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url/view in your question is not an admin page.

If you are using the generic `UpdateView` you can add a check to the `get_object` method and raise a [PermissionDenied](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/exceptions/#permissiondenied) error

```
class PorumbeiUpdateView(UpdateView):

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        object = super().get_object(queryset=queryset)
        if object.crescator != self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied()
        return object
```

If you have a function based view you would have to put the check at the beginning of the function after you get the object from the DB

```
def update_porembei(request, id):
    porembei = get_object_or_404(Porembei, id_porumbel=id)
    if porembei.crescator != self.request.user:
        raise PermissionDenied()
```

Comment: It worked. Can I customize this page(403 forbidden) or shoud I redirect to another page?

Comment: You can define a view in your base urls.py [`handler403`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#handler403) that will be called when this error is raised